# Словарь с именованными параметрами функции

Tags: javascript

```
function getElementByXpath(path, search_scope = document) {
  console.log(arguments)
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
```

Как мне получить словарь из аргументов функции с их значениями
в таком виде?

```
{
  path: '//span',
  search_scope: document
}
```

Переменная `arguments` выдает только значения параметров без их имен.

Comment: В таком виде никак. Только если кидать вместо всех аргументов один в виде объекта. Ну или внутри функции собирать параметры в объект.

Answer (score 0):

В случае функции из юзеркода, можно получить ее строковое представление - а значит, и имена параметров:

```js
function getElementByXpath(path, search_scope = document) {
  const argsMap = mapArguments(getElementByXpath, arguments);
  console.log(argsMap);
  // return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

function mapArguments(func, args) {
  const paramsStr = (func.toString().match(/^[^(]+\(([^)]+)/) ?? [0, ''])[1];
  return paramsStr.split(',').reduce((rslt, name, idx) => {
    rslt[name.replace(/=.*$/, '').trim()] = args[idx];
    return rslt;
  }, {});
}

getElementByXpath('//span', document);
```

Вывод в консоль объекта `document` не очень показателен, увы :)